# Process of transitioning a project from a collection of classes to a .dylib?

Tags: objective-c, dylib, dynamic-library

I've been working on a pet project for a few weeks now, and starting to think that it may get used by myself and a few friends.  At present, it's really just a pile of Objective-C classes in an XCode project with a main() I've been using to test various features.  Going forward it seems easiest to use this library in projects if I package it up as .dylib file.  As I've found with other languages, doing this as an afterthought is a nuisance that ideally is farmed out to the lowest rung. :)

I'm very new to the Objective-C/Xcode world, but according to Apple's ["Dynamic Library Programming Topics"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/Dynamic_Libraries.pdf), I'm under the impression that it's really just a matter of rejigging my interface files to be of the format:

```
@protocol Person
- (void)setName:(NSString*)name;
- (NSString*)name;
@end

@interface Person : NSObject <Person> {
    @private
NSString* _person_name;
}
@end
```

(taken from referenced Apple doc).

*Where:* I'm defining a protocol that contains the methods I wish to include for the classes to be contained in the .dylib, and then defining an interface that subclasses NSObject implementing the aforementioned protocol and declaring ivars in here.

*A few questions:*

Am I able to omit methods from the protocol that I don't wish to "EXPORT" to the dylib?

If I have subclasses of a class within the dylib, do I create another protocol for the subclass, and make the superclass of the newly created class implement that protocol?  For instance, if I were subclassing person:

```
@protocol CatPerson
/* any additional methods for CatPerson not in Person */
- (void) protractClaws;
- (void) retractClaws; 
@end

@interface CatPerson : Person <CatPerson> {
    @private
/* any additional ivars for CatPerson not in Person */
NSNumber *clawCount;
}
```

It's likely a very trivial question, but I'm trying to figure out everything I'll need to do before I go thru the gnashing of teeth of moving all the classes to a .dylib.

Answer (score 0):

Project->New Target…  select "dylib" in the panel that you get.  Make it the current target.  control-click on the groups & files tableview header, check "target membership".  Check the boxes next to the files you want included in your dylib.

Comment: Will this avoid having to add protocols for each interface?